# accessing the text value of last nested <tr> element with no id or class hooks

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I need to access the value of the 10th `<td>` element in the last row of a table.  I can't use an ID as a hook because only the table has an ID.  I've managed to make it work using the code below.  Unfortunately, its static.  I know I will always need the 10th `<td>` element, but I won't ever know which row it needs to be.  I just know it needs to be the last row in the table.  How would I replace `"tr[6]"` with the actual last `<tr>` dynamically?  (this is probably really easy, but this is literally my first time doing anything with ruby).

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
            test = page.css("tr[6]").map { |row| 
                    row.css("td[10]").text}

            puts test
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do:

```
page.at("tr:last td:eq(10)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to do anything else with the page you can actually make this a single line with

```
test = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).search("tr").last.search("td")[10].text
```

Otherwise (this will work):

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
test = page.search("tr").last.search("td")[10].text
puts test
```

**Example:**(Used a large table from another question on StackOverflow)

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dreyfuss")).search('table')[1].search('tr').last.search('td').children.map{|c| c.text}.join(" ")
#=> "2013 Paranoia Francis Cassidy"
```

Is there a particular reason you want an `Array` with 1 element? My example will return a string but you could easily modify it to return an `Array`.

Comment: Ruby arrays are zero-based, so the tenth element would be `[9]`.

Comment: @pguardiario you are correct. I feel no need to edit the answer as some things are better determined by the user. I try to remain true to the question while still allowing the OP to learn something along the way. Although +1 for your far more concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS pseudo class selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) for this:

```
page.css("table#the-table-id tr:last-of-type td:nth-of-type(10)")
```

This first selects the `<table>` with the appropriate `id`, then selects the last `<tr>` child of that table, and then selects the 10th `<td>` of that `<tr>`. The result is an array of all matching elements, if youexpect there to be only one you could use `at_css` instead.

If you prefer XPath, you could use this:

```
page.xpath("//table[@id='the-table-id']/tr[last()]/td[10]")
```

Comment: That css doesn't technically do what you think it does. Use `Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for` to see what I mean.

Comment: @pguardiario It does do what I think if I think it’s only being used on a `table` that only has `tr` children and `tr`s that only have `td` children :-) Thanks, I’ve updated it. `Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for` is useful, I didn’t know about that.